# How to add metadata and cover to an audio file in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, mp3, metadata, tags, aac

I am using Windows 8 have some MP3 files with the album cover embedded. I convert them to AAC (Advanced Audio Codec) format in order to gain some space.

The problems is that after I converted them, they lost all their metadata information for example Album, Genre, Year and Artist. Also they lost their embedded cover. So is there any app that can help to tag these files? And most importantly an app that can add an embedded cover to them?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it with [MP3Tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/), it supports AAC:

> Mp3tag is a powerful and yet easy-to-use tool to edit metadata of
>   common audio formats where it supports ID3v1, ID3v2.3, ID3v2.4, iTunes
>   MP4, WMA, Vorbis Comments and APE Tags.
>
> It can rename files based on the tag information, replace characters
>   or words in tags and filenames, import/export tag information, create
>   playlists and more.
>
> Mp3tag supports online database lookups from, e.g., Amazon, discogs,
>   or freedb, allowing you to automatically gather proper tags and cover
>   art for your music library.   Mp3tag supports the following audio
>   formats:

- **Advanced Audio Coding (aac)**
- ...

Answer (score 0):

There is a piece of free software named [Any Audio converter](http://www.any-audio-converter.com/) that you can use to convert your audio files—MP3, AAC, WMA, etc…—to each other and add/edit ID3 Tag information including: title, contributing artist, genre, album, year, track and comment. You can also add cover images to your audio files as well. You can even add lyrics to your audio files and download online videos and convert them to audio files.